# Do declaring a pointer in C also declare a variable with the same name

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

If i create a pointer like:

```
 int *pointer;
```

is also a variable (called pointer) created in the C Language? Why/why not?

Comment: Can you explain what you think a variable is? Is it a name that can be used in a certain way? Is it a place to store a value? What sort of value? As asked, your question may not be answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: Time to read the basics....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, A pointer is just like an int: a number. It happens to be a number that identifies a memory location, and if something is stored in that memory location you can call it an address. Like an int, a pointer can be stored in a variable. A variable that stores a pointer could be called a pointer variable.

Comment: Rather, an address is a number and pointer is the group name for the C variable types used for storing addresses. The term pointer does not exist outside C (and C++).

Comment: Pointer may or may not be an integer. In a specific implementation it is an integer. The C standard does not impose any such restriction.

Answer (score 6):

Let's get the terminology straight:

- `int *pointer` declares a variable
- Variables have a name and a type
- The name of the variable is `pointer`
- The type of the variable is "pointer to `int`"

Comment: Thanks, quite a refresher :)

Answer (score 2):

the question: can the code have a variable and a pointer with the same name?

The answer is NO, because those names are in the same 'scope;;

If they were each local to different functions (or different files) then they are in different 'scopes' then, YES then can have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a variable names `pointer` whose type is `int *`, i.e. a pointer to an `int`.  This does *not* give you space to store an `int`.

For example, if you did this:

```
int *pointer;
*pointer = 1;
```

You would be invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since you would be attempting to dereference an uninitialized pointer.

This however is valid.

```
int value;
int *pointer;
pointer = &value;
*pointer = 1;
```

In this example, we set `pointer` to the address of a variable of type `int`.  We are then able to dereference that variable to read/write the location it points to.

So to summarize, declaring a pointer to a type does not automatically give you space for the type itself.

Comment: despite all facts, how does this answers the question?

Comment: @dbush, I think the question asked is much simpler. Whether `pointer` is a variable or not.

Comment: This doesn't indeed answer the question. But I think it was good mention of the undefined behaviour. Thanks